# How can I conveniently initialize array of function pointers?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++20

```cpp
template<int I>;
void f(int value) { }

constexpr std::array<void(*)(int), 100> f_pointers = { &f<0>, &f<1>, &f<2>, ... &f<99> };
```

How can we fill f_pointers 0 ... 99 without typing them all out? Expecting the answer to involve `std::integer_sequence` unpacking, but reading [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion) doesn't make it obvious how to expand in this way. Working in C++20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <utility>


template<int N>
void f(){}

template<int... Indices>
constexpr auto create_functions(std::integer_sequence<int, Indices...>)
{
    return std::array {f<Indices>...};
}

constexpr auto arr = create_functions(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 100>{});

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So simple! Dunno how we missed the `f<Indices>...` syntax... This can be even smaller with lambda. Marking this as answer because you got there first.

Answer (score 2):

You could write it like this:

```
template<std::size_t ... I>
constexpr auto generate_fs(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::array { &f<I> ... };
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::array<void(*)(int), 100> f_pointers = [] { 
        return generate_fs(std::make_index_sequence<100>{}); 
    }();
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YPohq3).